# How to extrapolate values when missing data to avoid gaps in Highcharts (stacked areas)

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart with stacked area to represent global balance on a various number of saving accounts over time. The issue I have is the following :
At first I computed and generated a balance each and everyday, for all acounts. The problem is operations happen some days only, on some account only. In other terms, most of the time, the balance of the majority of account remains the same. So I decided to omit such "no change" values in the series to lighten the points and avoid performance hassle.

The problem I bumped into is that if you omit a value for a day, or put null, either way, you end up with a "gap" in the graph for the accounts where no value was provided. But that's not what I want : the account is still at the same balance and so the area should be filled in.

How can I do that ? Here is an example of what I get today (account2 has no value in 2019, and the gap appears) :

[image]

```
series: [{
    name: 'account1',
    data: [10, 9, 11, 11, 8, 13, 12, 14]
}, {
    name: 'account2',
    data: [13, 9, 10, 10, 8, null, 8, 6]
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4j9mz851/

What I would like
[image]

I tried http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls but with no success.

Here is how it works on non stacked areas : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-connectnulls-true/

Basically that thread on highchart github describes the need : having an 'interpolate' setting to connectNulls
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2069#issuecomment-38013782

Comment: What you want to achieve doesn't really make sense from a logical and accessibility point of view. If you use stacked area, as you probably know, subsequent series are based on the value (y) of a point from the previous series located in the same place (x), so if you set null for any of them, the next one will be based on it. The issues you linked to, as well as several others mentioned in it, have already been resolved and the correct use of connectNulls in the stacked area chart looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/twx8g12a/

Comment: One of the main contributors of highchart, Torstein Hønsi mentions a notion that would make sense to him : a 'interpolate' value for connectNulls, that would do what I expect https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2069#issuecomment-169326427
So I guess it kind of make sense, though maybe your remark is on whether it is easy/feasible to implement it ?

Comment: So in that case I suggest creating a new feature request (if one doesn't already exist), tag the author of the message and linking it in the description. If a workaround is possible, one of the developers should suggest it to you in response to the ticket when you ask for it